# file_put_contents() и несколько пользователей одновременно = конфликт?

Tags: cgi, php-fpm, файловая-система, php

Как php обходится с записью/чтением файлов, когда возможны одновременные конкурирующие обращения?

nginx + php-fpm на *nix хостинге, два рабочих процесса php-fpm.

К примеру, три поросёнка одновременно зашли на страницу, где выполняется запись в текстовый файл. Каждый пишет туда строчку со своим именем и временем обращения. Идеально одновременно.

Что будет в файле? Получат ли двое из трёх поросят ошибку?

Comment: В комментариях к ф-ии видел [упоминание методики](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php#82934), когда пишется новый файл, и затем происходит замена исходного обновлённым через переименование. Т.к. операция переименования в *nix атомарна, такой подход позволяет избежать конфликтов при чтении недописанного файла. Но это не решате вопроса одновременных попыток записи.

Comment: Чтоб поросята не чесали от удивления пятаки, увидев ошибку, можно использовать функцию [flock()](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.flock.html)

Comment: @Deonis как же быть с ajax-вызовом, которому не удалось получить блокировку? Ценнейшие данные же пропадут - из истории исчезнет Нуф-Нуф.

Comment: Не так часто сталкивался с поросячей темой, но возможно, чтоб спасти Нуф-нуфа, вам надо смотреть в сторону Comet. Например, [такой вариант](http://dklab.ru/lib/dklab_realplexor/)

Comment: @Deonis если хоть немного усложнять систему, то даже MySQL решит проблему одновременности. Интересно разобраться с файловым доступом —  для общего развития.

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c
Здесь кстати исходник обсуждаемой функции. Функция ставит замок на файл при начале записи и выкидывает исключение, если замок поставить не удалось.  
Вроде так.

Comment: Ерунду несёте. Для этого есть: flock()

Comment: @Genchik про flock() уже написал @Deonis, вторым комментом. При невозможности залочить файл для записи — что делать?

Comment: Не заметил коммента, прадон =) Сделать обработку try catch finally на блокировку. Вообще обрабатывать любые возможности ошибок, 75% работы - это поиск и фикс ошибок.

Comment: Хм. Может я не понял вопрос, но можно просто вызвать функцию так: `file_put_contents( $filename, $text, LOCK_EX );` скрипты попавшие на заблокированный файл подождут пока блокировку отдадут им и сделают запись.

Comment: Ух ты :-) Я в нем и три года назад отметился :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю как обстояли дела в далеком 2012, но начиная с PHP v5.1.0 в `file_put_contents` добавлена поддержка `LOCK_EX`. [Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php).

С данным флагом процесс будет ожидать, пока файл не будет освобожден другим процессом и после этого поставит блокировку на файл и запишет данные.

Сделаем несложный тест:

```
<?php
$unit = $_GET['unit'];
$test = preg_replace( "/\\D/", "", $_GET['test'] );
$fName = "test.txt";

function synchro() {
    time_sleep_until( ceil(time()/10+1)*10 );
}

$test1 = function () use( $unit, $fName ) {
    synchro();
    $end = microtime( true ) + 1;
    $count = 0;
    while ( $end > microtime(true) ) {
        file_put_contents( $fName, "unit $unit :\t$count\n", FILE_APPEND );
        $count++;
    }
};

$funcName = "test".$test;
$$funcName();
?>
```

В браузере откроем 3 вкладки. К примеру:

```
http://local/tests/flock.php?test=1&unit=1
http://local/tests/flock.php?test=1&unit=2
http://local/tests/flock.php?test=1&unit=3
```

В результате содержимое файла будет:

```
unit 3 :    0
unit 2 :    0
unit 1 :    0
unit 3 :    1
unit 2 :    1
unit 1 :    1
unit 3 :    2
unit 2 :    2
unit 1 :    2
unit 1 :    3
unit 2 :    3
unit 3 :    4
unit 1 :    4
unit 3 :    5
unit 1 :    5
unit 3 :    6
unit 2 :    5
unit 1 :    6
unit 1 :    7
unit 2 :    6
unit 3 :    7
unit 3 :    8
unit 1 :    8
unit 2 :    7
unit 3 :    9
unit 1 :    9
unit 3 :    10
unit 1 :    10
unit 2 :    9
unit 3 :    11
unit 2 :    10
unit 1 :    11
unit 1 :    12
unit 3 :    12
unit 2 :    11
unit 1 :    13
unit 3 :    13
unit 2 :    12
unit 2 :    13
unit 3 :    14
unit 3 :    15
unit 2 :    14
unit 2 :    15
unit 1 :    17
unit 3 :    16
unit 2 :    16
unit 2 :    17
unit 1 :    19
unit 3 :    18
unit 2 :    18
unit 1 :    20
unit 3 :    19
unit 3 :    20
unit 2 :    20
unit 1 :    21
unit 1 :    22
unit 2 :    21
unit 2 :    22
unit 3 :    22
unit 1 :    23
unit 2 :    23
unit 3 :    23
unit 2 :    24
unit 3 :    24
unit 3 :    25
unit 1 :    26
unit 2 :    25
unit 3 :    26
unit 1 :    27
unit 2 :    26
unit 3 :    27
unit 2 :    27
unit 3 :    28
unit 1 :    28
unit 2 :    28
unit 2 :    29
unit 3 :    30
unit 3 :    31
unit 2 :    31
unit 3 :    32
unit 2 :    32
unit 2 :    33
unit 3 :    33
unit 1 :    33
unit 1 :    34
unit 3 :    34
unit 2 :    34
unit 2 :    35
unit 1 :    35
unit 1 :    36
unit 3 :    36
unit 2 :    36
unit 2 :    37
unit 1 :    37
unit 2 :    38
unit 1 :    38
unit 1 :    39
unit 2 :    40
unit 1 :    40
unit 2 :    41
unit 3 :    40
unit 1 :    41
unit 2 :    42
unit 1 :    42
unit 3 :    42
unit 3 :    43
unit 3 :    44
unit 2 :    43
unit 2 :    44
unit 1 :    44
unit 3 :    45
unit 3 :    46
unit 1 :    45
unit 2 :    45
unit 2 :    46
unit 1 :    46
unit 3 :    47
unit 3 :    48
unit 1 :    47
unit 2 :    47
unit 3 :    49
unit 3 :    50
unit 2 :    48
unit 3 :    51
unit 2 :    49
unit 1 :    49
unit 3 :    52
unit 1 :    50
unit 2 :    50
unit 2 :    51
unit 1 :    51
unit 3 :    53
unit 3 :    54
unit 1 :    52
unit 2 :    52
unit 2 :    53
unit 1 :    53
unit 3 :    55
unit 2 :    54
unit 1 :    54
unit 3 :    56
unit 2 :    55
unit 2 :    56
unit 3 :    57
unit 1 :    55
unit 1 :    56
unit 2 :    57
unit 2 :    58
unit 1 :    57
unit 1 :    58
unit 2 :    59
unit 1 :    59
unit 3 :    61
unit 2 :    60
unit 1 :    60
unit 1 :    61
unit 3 :    62
unit 1 :    62
unit 1 :    63
unit 3 :    64
unit 2 :    63
unit 1 :    64
unit 3 :    65
unit 1 :    65
unit 1 :    66
unit 3 :    66
unit 1 :    67
unit 2 :    66
unit 2 :    67
unit 1 :    68
unit 2 :    68
unit 2 :    69
unit 1 :    70
unit 3 :    70
unit 2 :    70
unit 1 :    71
unit 3 :    71
unit 2 :    71
unit 2 :    72
unit 1 :    72
unit 3 :    72
unit 3 :    73
unit 2 :    73
unit 1 :    73
unit 1 :    74
unit 2 :    74
unit 3 :    74
unit 3 :    75
unit 2 :    75
unit 1 :    75
unit 3 :    76
unit 2 :    76
unit 3 :    77
unit 1 :    77
unit 1 :    78
unit 2 :    78
unit 3 :    79
unit 3 :    80
unit 1 :    79
unit 1 :    80
unit 2 :    80
unit 3 :    82
unit 3 :    83
unit 3 :    84
unit 3 :    85
unit 3 :    86
unit 1 :    81
unit 2 :    81
unit 3 :    87
unit 3 :    88
unit 2 :    82
unit 1 :    82
unit 1 :    83
unit 2 :    83
unit 3 :    89
unit 3 :    90
unit 2 :    84
unit 1 :    84
unit 1 :    85
unit 3 :    91
unit 3 :    92
unit 1 :    86
unit 2 :    86
unit 3 :    93
unit 1 :    87
unit 2 :    87
unit 3 :    94
unit 3 :    95
unit 1 :    88
unit 3 :    96
unit 1 :    89
unit 2 :    89
unit 3 :    97
unit 3 :    98
unit 1 :    91
unit 2 :    91
unit 1 :    92
unit 2 :    92
unit 3 :    99
unit 3 :    100
unit 1 :    93
unit 2 :    94
unit 3 :    101
unit 2 :    95
unit 3 :    102
unit 1 :    95
unit 1 :    96
unit 3 :    103
unit 2 :    96
unit 1 :    97
unit 2 :    97
unit 3 :    104
unit 2 :    98
unit 3 :    105
unit 1 :    98
unit 1 :    99
unit 3 :    106
unit 2 :    99
unit 3 :    107
unit 1 :    100
unit 3 :    108
unit 2 :    101
unit 1 :    101
unit 1 :    102
unit 2 :    102
unit 3 :    109
unit 1 :    103
unit 3 :    110
unit 2 :    103
unit 1 :    104
unit 2 :    104
unit 3 :    111
unit 3 :    112
unit 1 :    105
unit 3 :    113
unit 2 :    106
unit 1 :    106
unit 3 :    114
unit 3 :    115
unit 1 :    107
unit 2 :    107
unit 2 :    108
unit 1 :    108
unit 3 :    117
unit 2 :    109
unit 2 :    110
unit 1 :    110
unit 3 :    118
unit 3 :    119
unit 1 :    111
unit 1 :    112
unit 3 :    120
unit 1 :    113
unit 3 :    121
unit 3 :    122
unit 2 :    114
unit 1 :    114
unit 1 :    115
unit 2 :    115
unit 3 :    123
unit 1 :    116
unit 3 :    124
unit 2 :    116
unit 2 :    117
unit 3 :    125
unit 3 :    126
unit 2 :    118
unit 1 :    118
unit 2 :    119
unit 3 :    127
unit 3 :    128
unit 1 :    120
unit 2 :    120
unit 3 :    129
unit 2 :    121
unit 1 :    121
unit 1 :    122
unit 2 :    122
unit 3 :    130
unit 1 :    123
unit 2 :    123
unit 3 :    132
unit 2 :    124
unit 1 :    124
unit 1 :    125
unit 3 :    133
unit 2 :    125
unit 1 :    126
unit 2 :    126
unit 3 :    134
unit 1 :    127
unit 1 :    128
unit 2 :    127
unit 3 :    135
unit 2 :    128
unit 3 :    136
unit 1 :    129
unit 1 :    130
unit 3 :    137
unit 2 :    129
unit 2 :    130
unit 1 :    131
unit 3 :    139
unit 3 :    140
unit 2 :    132
unit 3 :    141
unit 3 :    142
unit 1 :    135
unit 2 :    134
unit 2 :    135
unit 3 :    143
unit 1 :    136
unit 1 :    137
unit 3 :    144
unit 2 :    136
unit 1 :    138
unit 3 :    145
unit 1 :    139
unit 1 :    140
unit 2 :    138
unit 3 :    146
unit 3 :    147
unit 2 :    139
unit 1 :    141
unit 1 :    142
unit 2 :    140
unit 3 :    148
unit 3 :    149
unit 2 :    141
unit 2 :    142
unit 1 :    144
unit 3 :    150
unit 2 :    143
unit 1 :    145
unit 2 :    144
unit 2 :    145
unit 1 :    146
unit 3 :    152
unit 3 :    153
unit 2 :    146
unit 1 :    148
unit 3 :    154
unit 1 :    149
unit 3 :    155
unit 2 :    148
unit 2 :    149
unit 3 :    156
unit 1 :    150
unit 1 :    151
unit 3 :    157
unit 2 :    150
unit 2 :    151
unit 3 :    158
unit 1 :    152
unit 2 :    152
unit 3 :    159
unit 1 :    153
unit 2 :    153
unit 3 :    160
unit 3 :    161
unit 1 :    154
unit 3 :    162
unit 3 :    163
unit 1 :    155
unit 1 :    156
unit 3 :    164
unit 1 :    157
unit 3 :    165
unit 2 :    157
unit 1 :    158
unit 2 :    158
unit 2 :    159
unit 1 :    160
unit 3 :    167
unit 3 :    168
unit 1 :    161
unit 2 :    160
unit 2 :    161
unit 3 :    169
unit 1 :    162
unit 1 :    163
unit 2 :    162
unit 3 :    170
unit 1 :    164
unit 2 :    163
unit 3 :    171
unit 1 :    165
unit 2 :    164
unit 3 :    172
unit 1 :    166
unit 2 :    165
unit 2 :    166
unit 1 :    167
unit 3 :    173
unit 3 :    174
unit 2 :    167
unit 1 :    168
unit 1 :    169
unit 3 :    175
unit 2 :    168
unit 2 :    169
unit 1 :    170
unit 3 :    176
unit 3 :    177
unit 1 :    171
unit 2 :    170
unit 2 :    171
unit 1 :    172
unit 3 :    178
unit 3 :    179
unit 2 :    172
unit 1 :    174
unit 3 :    180
unit 2 :    173
unit 1 :    175
unit 3 :    181
unit 2 :    174
unit 2 :    175
unit 1 :    177
unit 3 :    182
unit 2 :    176
unit 1 :    178
unit 3 :    183
unit 2 :    177
unit 1 :    179
```

Явно видно, что некоторые записи пропущены.
Теперь добавим флаг `LOCK_EX`:

```
file_put_contents( $fName, "unit $unit :\t".$count."\n", FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX );
```

Результат:

```
unit 1 :    0
unit 2 :    0
unit 3 :    0
unit 1 :    1
unit 2 :    1
unit 3 :    1
unit 1 :    2
unit 2 :    2
unit 3 :    2
unit 1 :    3
unit 2 :    3
unit 3 :    3
unit 1 :    4
unit 2 :    4
unit 3 :    4
unit 1 :    5
unit 2 :    5
unit 3 :    5
unit 1 :    6
unit 2 :    6
unit 3 :    6
unit 1 :    7
unit 2 :    7
unit 3 :    7
unit 1 :    8
unit 2 :    8
unit 3 :    8
unit 1 :    9
unit 2 :    9
unit 3 :    9
unit 1 :    10
unit 2 :    10
unit 3 :    10
unit 1 :    11
unit 2 :    11
unit 3 :    11
unit 1 :    12
unit 2 :    12
unit 3 :    12
unit 1 :    13
unit 2 :    13
unit 3 :    13
unit 1 :    14
unit 2 :    14
unit 3 :    14
unit 1 :    15
unit 2 :    15
unit 3 :    15
unit 1 :    16
unit 2 :    16
unit 3 :    16
unit 1 :    17
unit 2 :    17
unit 3 :    17
unit 1 :    18
unit 2 :    18
unit 3 :    18
unit 1 :    19
unit 2 :    19
unit 3 :    19
unit 1 :    20
unit 2 :    20
unit 3 :    20
unit 1 :    21
unit 2 :    21
unit 3 :    21
unit 1 :    22
unit 2 :    22
unit 3 :    22
unit 1 :    23
unit 2 :    23
unit 3 :    23
unit 1 :    24
unit 2 :    24
unit 3 :    24
unit 1 :    25
unit 2 :    25
unit 3 :    25
unit 1 :    26
unit 2 :    26
unit 3 :    26
unit 1 :    27
unit 2 :    27
unit 3 :    27
unit 1 :    28
unit 2 :    28
unit 3 :    28
unit 1 :    29
unit 2 :    29
unit 3 :    29
unit 1 :    30
unit 2 :    30
unit 3 :    30
unit 1 :    31
unit 2 :    31
unit 3 :    31
unit 1 :    32
unit 2 :    32
unit 3 :    32
unit 1 :    33
unit 2 :    33
unit 3 :    33
unit 1 :    34
unit 2 :    34
unit 3 :    34
unit 1 :    35
unit 2 :    35
unit 3 :    35
unit 1 :    36
unit 2 :    36
unit 3 :    36
unit 1 :    37
unit 2 :    37
unit 3 :    37
unit 1 :    38
unit 2 :    38
unit 3 :    38
unit 1 :    39
unit 2 :    39
unit 3 :    39
unit 1 :    40
unit 2 :    40
unit 3 :    40
unit 1 :    41
unit 2 :    41
unit 3 :    41
unit 1 :    42
unit 2 :    42
unit 3 :    42
unit 1 :    43
unit 2 :    43
unit 3 :    43
unit 1 :    44
unit 2 :    44
unit 3 :    44
unit 1 :    45
unit 2 :    45
unit 3 :    45
unit 1 :    46
unit 2 :    46
unit 3 :    46
unit 1 :    47
unit 2 :    47
unit 3 :    47
unit 1 :    48
unit 2 :    48
unit 3 :    48
unit 1 :    49
unit 2 :    49
unit 3 :    49
unit 1 :    50
unit 2 :    50
unit 3 :    50
unit 2 :    51
unit 1 :    51
unit 3 :    51
unit 2 :    52
unit 1 :    52
unit 3 :    52
unit 2 :    53
unit 1 :    53
unit 3 :    53
unit 2 :    54
unit 1 :    54
unit 3 :    54
unit 2 :    55
unit 1 :    55
unit 3 :    55
unit 2 :    56
unit 1 :    56
unit 3 :    56
unit 2 :    57
unit 1 :    57
unit 3 :    57
unit 2 :    58
unit 1 :    58
unit 3 :    58
unit 2 :    59
unit 1 :    59
unit 3 :    59
unit 2 :    60
unit 1 :    60
unit 3 :    60
unit 2 :    61
unit 1 :    61
unit 3 :    61
unit 2 :    62
unit 1 :    62
unit 3 :    62
unit 2 :    63
unit 1 :    63
unit 3 :    63
unit 2 :    64
unit 1 :    64
unit 3 :    64
unit 2 :    65
unit 1 :    65
unit 3 :    65
unit 2 :    66
unit 1 :    66
unit 3 :    66
unit 2 :    67
unit 1 :    67
unit 3 :    67
unit 2 :    68
unit 1 :    68
unit 3 :    68
unit 2 :    69
unit 1 :    69
unit 3 :    69
unit 2 :    70
unit 1 :    70
unit 3 :    70
unit 2 :    71
unit 1 :    71
unit 3 :    71
unit 2 :    72
unit 1 :    72
unit 3 :    72
unit 2 :    73
unit 1 :    73
unit 3 :    73
unit 2 :    74
unit 1 :    74
unit 3 :    74
unit 2 :    75
unit 1 :    75
unit 3 :    75
unit 2 :    76
unit 1 :    76
unit 3 :    76
unit 2 :    77
unit 1 :    77
unit 3 :    77
unit 2 :    78
unit 1 :    78
unit 3 :    78
unit 2 :    79
unit 1 :    79
unit 3 :    79
unit 2 :    80
unit 1 :    80
unit 3 :    80
```

Все идеально. Ничего не было пропущено.

Comment: Спасибо за интерес спустя 3 года, и проделанные тесты!

Comment: @Sergiks да это комьюнити вопрос наверх топнуло :) Ему спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Пишите данные от трех поросят в БД, по крону, или руками запускайте скрипт, Который будет генерить файл с нужными данными исходя из записей в БД. Весьма надежный способ сохранить ценные данные :]

Comment: Всё так, только вопрос не об этом.